# Laravel 5.5 How can I get the accessToken of a custom user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I can access the personal accessToken of a loggedIn user in Passport Authentication by

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->AauthAcessToken();
```

But for a custom user i tried for the personal accessToken as following but gives null.

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
$user->AauthAcessToken();
```

How can I get the accessToken of a custom user?

Comment: No.`Auth::user()->AauthAcessToken()` gives the right result

Comment: Are you passing the `$id` into the function? when trying to find the User

Comment: @Option I guess yes, otherwise he should get an exception `trying to get property of null`

Comment: Yes. Everything is correct. I just want to know the method used to fetch the token of a custom user.

Comment: Where is the function `AauthAccessToken` defined?

Comment: For the custom user id I get the `print_r($user)` gives the accessToken array as null `[accessToken:protected] => Laravel\Passport\Token Object
        () `

Comment: Hareesh, your `$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();` should work fine as long as you have passed `$id` into the func and the accesstoken is stored within the users database table.

Comment: @Option `$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();` gives correct result array. But it does not gives the accessToken.

Comment: what if u make `$user->accessToken` ?

Comment: Hareesh, if the accesstoken is stored within the database table of `users` i'd suggest checking User.php model and ensuring it's within the `$fillable` otherwise it will not read / write it

Comment: @Option It has not been stored in users table. I'm using the passport here for Auth

Comment: If it's not being stored then you won't be able to pull it with that query....

Comment: Check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code.

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
$user->getAccessToken();
```

You will get user's object so u just need to get access_token key.
Like:

`$user->getAccessToken()['access_token'];`

Thanks,